# Circular dependency when upgrading to Gradle 5

Tags: gradle, kotlin, circular-dependency

Our project worked until I tried to upgrade to Gradle 5. There the first thing it complained was that `/` isn't a good character for multi-projects, e.g. `bla/blub` isn't valid, so we changed this to `bla:blub` (even though the error message said `:` also isn't valid). But now we apparently have a circular dependency which didn't exist before with Gradle 4:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:lap:server:classes
\--- :lap:server:compileJava
     +--- :lap:server:compileKotlin
     |    \--- :lap:server:jar
     |         +--- :lap:server:classes (*)
     |         +--- :lap:server:compileKotlin (*)
     |         \--- :lap:server:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
     |              \--- :lap:server:classes (*)
     \--- :lap:server:jar (*)
```

Why could this be?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was indeed with the `:` notation in our `settings.gradle`. Now that I've changed all the nested projects to `-` the problem is resolved.

More concretely, before we had something like:

```
include 'common/server',
    'someproject/server',
    'someproject/common',
    'someproject/search',
    ...
```

which worked with gradle 4.

Then in Gradle 5 I've changed it to

```
include 'common:server',
    'someproject:server',
    'someproject:common',
    'someproject:search',
    ...
```

which caused the issue, presumably because `someproject:common` depended on `common:server` or something of the likes.

Now that I've changed it to

```
include 'common-server'
project(':common-server').projectDir = file('common/server')

include 'someproject-server'
project(':someproject-server').projectDir = file('someproject/server')

include 'someproject-common'
project(':someproject-common').projectDir = file('someproject/common')
```

everything works like a charm. By the way, the error with the circular dependency is also reproducible in Gradle 4, it's just that there we still had the `/` notation.

Comment: Wow, great detective skills.  Consider posting this over at : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847  (I think its the same trouble area). but this solution may be the best workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who stumble on this question.

see : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847

in a multi project setup, a duplicate "shortname" will throw in a monkey wrench:

from the url above:

```
myApp
  - client
    - common
  - server
    - common
```

Even though it should be 2 distinct entries, the duplicate (shortname) of "common" is the issue/bug.

I ended up doing this: (my code is different names of course) (but the idea is)

```
myApp
  - client
    - clientcommon
  - server
    - servercommon
```

to disambiguate.

The url has some other ideas.

What I saw in my code was, the built jars looked something like this:

common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

So that was what clued me in to "ahhh, maybe I have ambiguous issue with the shortname".  And finally found that github-gradle link.